# First time Running MongoDB: ERROR in opening config file.

Tags: macos, mongodb

```
$ mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
ERROR: could not read from config file

Allowed options:

General options:
  -h [ --help ]               show this usage information
  --version                   show version information
```

---

When I run "mongo" command terminal becomes unresponsive:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test

--- no response ----
```

Please note: I'm running MongoDB on MacOS X for the first time.

Comment: Are you sure `mongod` has the rights to touch the conf file? Also what is in the conf file?

Comment: Have you tried using homebrew on Mac to install mongodb? Its real easy and will set you up fine very quickly. I use it all the time to upgrade and for initial mongo install.

Comment: I manually edited the contents of the config file and ran the homebrew install of mongodb. Its working now. Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default mongo.config file on installation did not have:

```
port = 27017
```

i updated the config file from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/

the running the mongo command in Terminal works fine:

```
    mongo
```

did not fall into an infinite loop instead the mongodb prompt > was activated.

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.5
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings: 
Fri Jul 12 02:17:19.667 [initandlisten] 
Fri Jul 12 02:17:19.667 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed on a previous mongodb installation in linux you shoud check for the path 
/etc/mongod.conf 
if mongod.conf is present with some other name change it to mongod.conf and it works fine after 
sudo service mongod restart